# Can't Create Debian Package for QT App

Tags: packaging, qt

I can't create package. 
I was try to create with [this tutorial](https://bhavyanshu.me/how-to-make-debian-packages-for-qt-c-based-applications/11/10/2014/).
Error is when I write the last one command: `pdebuild --debbuildopts -sa`

Errors:

```
parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l1): found change data where expected first heading
LINE:    doleo (0.63) unreleasted; urgency=low
parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l5): found eof where expected more change data or trailer
parsechangelog/debian: error: Can't call method "as_string" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Changelog.pm line 251.

dpkg-parsechangelog: error: changelog parser /usr/lib/dpkg/parsechangelog/debian gave error exit status 255
parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l1): found change data where expected first heading
LINE:    doleo (0.63) unreleasted; urgency=low
parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l5): found eof where expected more change data or trailer
parsechangelog/debian: error: Can't call method "as_string" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Changelog.pm line 251.

dpkg-parsechangelog: error: changelog parser /usr/lib/dpkg/parsechangelog/debian gave error exit status 255
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: syntax error in debian/control at line 1: continued value line not in field
W: Unmet build-dependency in source
parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l1): found change data where expected first heading
LINE:    doleo (0.63) unreleasted; urgency=low
parsechangelog/debian: warning:     debian/changelog(l5): found eof where expected more change data or trailer
parsechangelog/debian: error: Can't call method "as_string" on an undefined value at /usr/share/perl5/Dpkg/Changelog.pm line 251.

dpkg-buildpackage: error: changelog parser /usr/lib/dpkg/parsechangelog/debian gave error exit status 255
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you post the contents of `debian/changelog` .  If it is long, upload it to http://paste.ubuntu.com.